# CSS Overflow issue in IE

Tags: css

I having problem to make the overflow hidden if the width is over the line
anyone know how to do it?

It does not work for IE at all.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:12pt;
}
table.excel {
    border-collapse:collapse;    
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:inherit;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
}

.datacell {
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
</style>

<table class="excel" width="194px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:30px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:64px;">A</td>
        <td style="width:100px;">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:50px;">1</td>
        <td class="datacell" style="max-width:64px;">
            <div style="float:left;min-width:160px;white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; position:relative;background-color:#FFFFFF;">I like to eat McDonalds double<br>cheese burger, i am lovin it!</div>
        </td>        
        <td class="datacell">aa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't even have `overflow: hidden` anywhere in there.

Comment: He does in `td.datacell > div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *width* and *height* attributes to your *overflow-hidden* `<div>`.

Comment: I think it works for firefox, chrome and safari, but it wont work for IE 8 so far.

Answer (score 0):

I try changing `min-width:160px;` in `div`'s style to `width:160px;` & it solved your problem.